# Build Linux for a Raspberry Pi without /opt/vc?

Tags: linux, compiling, raspberry-pi

Now that the vc4 DRM/GBM driver has been making progress, is it possible to build Linux (not just the kernel but the entire operating system eg. Linux From Scratch) without libraries and programs from `/opt/vc`? Would it work? Right now having /opt/vc means the normal BLFS (Beyond Linux From Scratch) setup for X11 does not work with many programs because they link at compile-time to libraries in /opt/vc and at runtime search /usr/lib.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What's /opt/vc? Googling indicates to me that it's some sort of RPI-specific thing.

Comment: /opt/vc/* are broadcom's (once proprietary) libraries and utilities to utilize the VideoCore IV GPU for graphics acceleation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only things special you should need for building Raspberry Pi with graphics support, compared to other ARMs currently:

- linux-next kernel (to get the devicetree for vc4, until 4.7 is released)
- rasperrypi/firmware on a vfat partition

However, building everything from scratch will be an exercise in frustration, and I would recommend starting from an existing distribution with ARM support.